What are all of the instances in which Christ discusses marriage?
I am not entirely convinced that the idea of marriages being divinely blessed or preferable of a Christian life is entirely Christian. It seems, aside from Matthew 19, that Christ is entirely unconcerned with the concept of marriage and teaches that a chaste life is the ideal Christian life. Most of the sentiment around marriage in Christian life seems to come from Pauline writings.
Are there any other examples of Christ discussing the topic of erotic love/marriage aside from this discussion around divorce/eunuchs?

Paul of course does not teach that marriage is preferable to singleness!

Asking for 'all instances' is requesting a text search which I believe is of-topic on the site. It is usually suggested that the OP should refer to a Concordance.

I’m voting to close this question because it is requesting a text search.

@NigelJ I mean, strictly looking up "marriage" in a concordance would not necessarily yield every result of somebody discussing marriage in the Bible? There's a number of words one would have to search "man", "woman", "marriage", "divorce", etc.

@curiousdannii I suppose there is no argument for marriage being preferable to singleness, but it seems that some Christians, especially in the US, believe that marriage is a divinely blessed state of being; one that is not necessarily less preferable to chastity; one that is not a shortcoming or in some way a concession. The way I interpret the Gospels, marriage is always something of a concession to appease physical desires in a God honoring way and always less preferable than chastity.

If everyone remained chaste, from today onwards, the human race would die out in about 50 years. (No children to pay the pensions of the aged, unable to work.) How does that honour God ? Who said 'Be fruitful and multiply'. (Whose purposes are - as  Father - 'to bring many sons to glory.) There is a purpose in it all.

I mean, it seems pretty unChristian to believe a verse in Genesis holds as much weight as a red-lettered verse when they contradict each other. It is of course blatantly obvious that humans will always sin, that some will always be unchaste and procreate and the race will live on. That doesn't change the fact that it would be preferable for you as an individual to be chaste. This isn't a matter of "what should everyone do?" but a "what am I called to do?".

It is more a case of what did God command to do . . . . . .  'Be fruitful and multiply.' I don't see any 'contradiction' myself. The commandment of God and the Purpose of the Father do not contradict one another :  'multiply humanity' and 'bring many sons to glory'.

Ah yes, this question does not appear to be about Christianity

I'm Orthodox, my answer will reflect that perspective.

Is it insufficient that it is mentioned once? Certainly over the years Jesus likely taught about marriage and divorce multiple times, it was significant enough that it was included in the Bible.
So yes, the primary teaching about Marriage comes from Matthew 19.
I find it extremely odd that you think Christ is unconcerned with marriage when he specifically says in verses 10-12

The disciples said to him, “If this is the situation between a husband and wife, it is better not to marry.” (verse 10)


Jesus replied, “Not everyone can accept this word, but only those to whom it has been given. 12 For there are eunuchs who were born that way, and there are eunuchs who have been made eunuchs by others—and there are those who choose to live like eunuchs for the sake of the kingdom of heaven. The one who can accept this should accept it.” (verse 11-12)

Jesus specifically says that not everyone can accept this. That is to say the majority of people will not be sexually moral if they are not married. This means of course that the majority of people should get married.

In the orthodox church, marriage is considered to be the oldest institution of divine law as it was instituted with the creation of Adam and Eve. It was good when humanity existed in paradise, it most certainly is still good today. It is a miniature version of the Church. A marriage is an ikon of the Church. And with God's blessing and involvement the marriage elevates those involved and points them on the proper path toward salvation. (Having someone around to help you and point out how you need to improve makes you a better human as well)

You mentioned Paul, and certainly he compares marriage with Christ and the church. And this is also seen when Christ speaks in Matthew 9:15 / Mark 2:19-20 / Luke 5:34-35.

So while there is no additional "quotes" from Christ about the subject without it being an allegory for Christ and the Church, and so it is all said in Matthew 19, and written about in many other books. (Hebrews, Romans, Ephesians, etc.)
I hope you can see that Marriage is Divinely blessed and has existed since creation itself. It was good at the beginning, before sin had corrupted humanity. There is definitely a lot of teaching on how IF you can be celibate and chaste you should. But honestly that is a very very very big IF. And what about children? We are supposed to be like them, raise them to love God, and all of that is possible through marriage. Some are chosen to NOT marry, the majority are not. This is why most men become fathers of families, and not bishops. :)

Erotic love is also from God, but that is mostly shown in song of solomon and would be another long answer about the types of Love. God gave us erotic love as well as the other types.

Edit: Here is another way to look at it. You should either be a monastic or be married. Both are ways to love God, both will guide you further towards theosis and keep you properly aligned towards God.
Let me use an overly simplified metaphor with "learning".

You could remain a student forever, devoutly learning.
You could go out and practice and teach what you learned.

Both of these paths will give you deeper and deeper insight into what you are learning. Neither is superior to the other and depend on the person involved.
Certainly to become a Bishop that is crazed with sexual temptation is not good. And if you were someone who is low in Eros love you would likely disappoint and neglect your partner which is not good.

Right, it seems that the order of preference would be:

Single and chaste
Married, unchaste, but fidelitous
Married, unchaste, and infidelitous or single and unchaste

But, in making this assumption, we must assume that "sinfullness" is quantifiable in some way?

Also, it feels hard to believe that Christ would deem marriage as an "institution of divine law" when he explicitly says that chastity is preferable. This sentiment feels very Jewish, i.e. one that would have changed with the New Covenant, similar to how Christ rescinded the Mosaic law of retaliation in Mat. 5:38-. "You have heard that it was said...but I tell you" - you have previously been taught in Genesis that marriage is a divine institution, but I am here to say chastity is preferable.

@DavidChopin There is only two preferences from what I can see. You either are being sinful or not. Marriage and monastic life styles are the pathways that guide you away from sin and are dependent on the person involved. If you are called to be a eunuch for the Kingdom of Heaven, then you should accept your calling. If you are called to procreate and guide children towards the Kingdom of Heaven then you should accept your calling.  You definitely shouldn't attempt the wrong path for you, and you definitely shouldn't be "single and unchaste"

Some churches attempt to quantify sinfulness (Catholics famously do this), the orthodox church does not. Think of it like this: I am sick from a deadly poison, so I go to the all powerful Physician. He gives me the antidote that I should take, I however routinely drink more and more poison which hurts me more and more. I still am taking the antidote and I do my best to not drink more poison. At no point am I "fallen out of Grace", I have tripped and God is there to help pick me up out of the absolute filth I landed in and guide me toward His Kingdom.

The first example that comes to mind is the multiple times he talks about being the bridegroom, or the parable of ten virgins. If marriage wasn't important he could have used a different comparison.
Matthew 9:15 (see also Mark 2:19-20 and Luke 5:34-35)

15 Jesus answered, “How can the guests of the bridegroom mourn while he is with them? The time will come when the bridegroom will be taken from them; then they will fast.

John also reference's Christ as being the bridegroom in John 3:26-29
Matthew 25:1-13

“At that time the kingdom of heaven will be like ten virgins who took their lamps and went out to meet the bridegroom.
2 Five of them were foolish and five were wise.
3 The foolish ones took their lamps but did not take any oil with them.
4 The wise ones, however, took oil in jars along with their lamps.
5 The bridegroom was a long time in coming, and they all became drowsy and fell asleep.
6 “At midnight the cry rang out: ‘Here’s the bridegroom! Come out to meet him!’
7 “Then all the virgins woke up and trimmed their lamps. 8 The foolish ones said to the wise, ‘Give us some of your oil; our lamps are going out.’
9 “‘No,’ they replied, ‘there may not be enough for both us and you. Instead, go to those who sell oil and buy some for yourselves.’
10 “But while they were on their way to buy the oil, the bridegroom arrived. The virgins who were ready went in with him to the wedding banquet. And the door was shut.
11 “Later the others also came. ‘Lord, Lord,’ they said, ‘open the door for us!’
12 “But he replied, ‘Truly I tell you, I don’t know you.’
13 “Therefore keep watch, because you do not know the day or the hour.
'


Another reference to marriage is Jesus' first miracle was turning water to wine, at a wedding he attended
I also don't think Jesus' talk of divorce (Mark 10:2-12) should be discarded so easily. As in the middle, v 7-9, he basically says marriage is why a man leaves his family:

‘For this reason a man will leave his father and mother and be united to his wife,
8 and the two will become one flesh.’ So they are no longer two, but one flesh.
9 Therefore what God has joined together, let no one separate.

